# how to change formatting of calculated values(text area) in spotfire using iron python

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to toggle Calculated values in text area format from number to currency and vice-versa from a drop down using iron python and i didn't find anything.
please let me know if there is a way to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: This is pretty broad... can you elaborate with some sample data and expected output? This isn't a code writing service. This help page should get you started... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you cannot change the input field's category, since the actual property attached has a specified Data Type.  You CAN create two separate input fields, one of each data type, and use ironpython to hide or show one or the other and determine which one is being used... wherever.